# how to handle key - value pair in dropdown angular advance search nox

Tags: angularjs, search, advanced-search

In Advance searchbox, i am able to display list of values in dropdown like below example it contains only list of values, but now i want to handle key-value pair with dropdown in advance search box.

**only list of values in dropdown Example:**

```
"key1": {
      "name": "name",
      "key": "key1",
      "placeholder": "some text...",
      "type": "text",
      "restrictToSuggestedValues": true,
     "suggestedValues": [
         "value1",
         "value2",
         "value3",
         "value4"        
      ]
    }
```

but i want handle like key-value pair

```
 "key1": {
      "name": "name",
      "key": "key1",
      "placeholder": "some text...",
      "type": "text",
      "restrictToSuggestedValues": true,
     **"suggestedValues": {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" "value2",
        "key3" : "value3",
        "key4" : "value4"        
      }**
    }
```

html part:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <nit-advanced-searchbox template-url="assets/templates/angular-advanced-searchbox.html"
                                ng-model="model.searchParams"
                                parameters="model.availableSearchParams"
                                parameters-display-limit="50"
                                advance-search="advSearch()"
                                placeholder="Search...">
        </nit-advanced-searchbox>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" ng-click='actionsMethod(model.searchParams)'>
                search 
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think, will need more explain.

Comment: provide your html template